# jQuery Mobile Collapsible appearing twice

Tags: jquery-mobile, collapsable, jquery-mobile-collapsible, codiqa

I have a jQuery Mobile page with a dynamically generated collapsible. It works great, except if I leave the page then return to it. When that happens, the collapsible appears twice. A refresh fixes the issue but that's obviously not a good solution. Others on here have described similar symptoms, but their solutions didn't work for me. I'm hoping someone can help me out. I think I may be misusing pageinit...

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 with jQuery Mobile 1.3.1. I'm using Codiqa to generate my pages, hence why I'm on jQuery 1.3.1. I generated the code such that every page is a separate html file.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Characters | PCT</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <link href="css/codiqa.ext.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/codiqa.ext.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.15.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/pct.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <div data-role="page" data-control-title="Characters" id="characters" 
      class="character_page">
   <script>
  $(document).on("pageinit", "#characters", function() {
    var charQuery = new Parse.Query("Character");
            charQuery.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
            charQuery.find({
           success: function(results) {
                  for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                var object = results[j];
        var charName = object.get('charName');
        var charNumActions = object.get('charNumActions');
        var charSpd = object.get('charSpd');

                    $("#char_list").append("<div data-role='collapsible'><h4> " + 
                    charName + "</h4><p><strong>Number of Actions:</strong> " + 
                    charNumActions + "</p><p><strong>Spd:</strong> " + charSpd + "</p>
                    <a data-role='button' class='edit_button' 
                    href='edit_character.html?charname=" + charName + "' data-icon='edit' 
                    data-iconpos='left'>Edit</a><a data-role='button' 
                    id='delete_char_button' class='delete_button' data-inline='true' 
                    data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='left'>Delete</a></div>");

                    $("#char_list").collapsibleset("refresh");
                $(".edit_button").buttonMarkup();
        $(".delete_button").buttonMarkup();
         }
             }
         }); 
    });
</script> 
  <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
```

Thank you in advance for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

Based on your edited OP and comment below, when using *single page model*, functions/JS code that is related to a specific page should be placed inside that page's div.

jQuery Mobile uses Ajax to load pages, it loads all libraries and code of first loaded page's `head` tag, and neglects the rest as it loads *only* `data-role="page"` div.

```
<div data-role="page" id="characters">
  <script>
    <!-- place code here -->
  </script>
</div>
```

---

Because you bind to `pageinit` without specifying a page. The code will be executed whenever a *page* is initiated.

You should bind it to *page id* to fire once only.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page_id", function () {
  // code
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! It works much better now except for one thing: on the initial load, it doesn't display any at all. I have to click refresh. Once refresh is clicked, it works fine from there.

Comment: @mrbranden are you using _single page model_? each page in a separate HTML file? if yes, place the code inside the target page.

Comment: That is correct, I'm using single page model. I placed the JS in the target page (see edited code above), which fixes the problem with it not appearing on page load... but now we're back to printing double! 
Is it necessary to add the _pageid_ to the pageinit if it's included in the page div itself? Thanks again!

Comment: If page id is added and the problem persists, use `.one` instead of `.on` @mrbranden

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, you've made my afternoon! :-)